# Jenkins shows JMeter script failure even though the script actually passed

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I have my jmeter script running from a jenkins job but it is always reporting it as failed even though the script actually passed.  I am using the 'Publish Performance test result report Post-build Action.  Please see screenshot.  What am I doing wrong?  Why does it always show an error even though the actual jmeter script is passing?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this!  Use this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

In a rules file containing this line:
    error /FAILED/

In the script add a beanshell Assertion for each HTTP Request that will log messages for successes and failures.  Here's one example:

```
String testscenario = "TEST SCENARIO: ";
String requestName = "Find Stuff";
String findStuff = "${MyStuff}";
String custName = "${CustName}";
String respData = new String(ResponseData);

if (respData.contains(findStuff))
{
    log.info(testscenario+"Passed. "+requestName+" MyStuff for Cust: " + 
custName + " containing " + findStuff + " returned.");      
    print(testscenario+"Passed. "+requestName+" MyStuff for Customer " + 
custName + " containing " + findStuff + " returned.");  
} else 
{
    log.error(testscenario+"*FAILED. "+requestName);    
    print(testscenario+"*FAILED. "+requestName);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the threshold for Unstable/Failure to 0, so even 0 consider as failure.

Increase the thresholds for Unstable and Failed

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried your suggestion and it seemed to work at first but now it's showing a pass when the script actually failed (false positive).

Comment: You probably checking against build with more failures. Check against build without failures